# href link not append runtime in anchor tag on $.mobile.changePage in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new in jquery mobile, developing application in iphone using phonegap, I am redirecting one page to another using:

```js
$.mobile.changePage('restaurant_detail.html?iInfoId='+ this.id + ext_link+'&type='+type, {transition: "slide"});
```

On 'restaurant_detail.html' page append footer tab link on page show event, but its not append link href attribute in tab link:

```js
$('#restaurant_detail').live('pageshow',function(event){ $('#f_order').attr('href','order_history.html');});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="footer_button" rel="external" data-role="none" id="f_order">
    <img src="img/footer_icon_order.png" alt=""/>
    <span>Order History</span>
</a>
```

Please give answer, Thanks in advance.

On restaurant.js page code:

```js
$('.restaurant_item').live("click",function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('restaurant_detail.html?iInfoId='+ this.id + ext_link+'&type='+type, {transition: "slide"});    
});
```

To redirect here restaurant_detail.js

```js
$('#restaurant_detail').on('pageshow',function(event){
if(event.handled !== true){
   if(sesObj.get('sess_iUserId') == null){
        $('#f_order').attr('href','register.html?type=order');      
   }else{
        $('#f_order').attr('href','order_history.html');
   }
    event.handled = true;       
}
return false;   
});
```

restaurant_detail.html

```html
<div data-role="footer" class="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div class="footer-container">        
    <a href="#" class="footer_button" rel="external" data-role="none" id="f_order">
        <img src="img/footer_icon_order.png" alt=""/>
        <span>Order History</span>
    </a>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `live()` method has been deprecated and it's use should be avoided. Use the `on()` method instead and delegate the event handler to the body or document, i.e:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#restaurant_detail", function() {
    $('#f_order').attr('href','order_history.html');
});
```

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Are you getting any errors? Can you describe 'not working' in a bit more detail?

Comment: Call the on() method on the document, and pass the element selector as the second argument to on() in restaurant_detail.js

Comment: What happened? You need to give us something to work with here. What is not working? Is the event not firing? Can you add a console.log() statement inside the handler and see the log message? Do you get errors in the console? Can you link to a jsFiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17292/discussion-between-ved-and-danwellman)